# Harvard Style citation and Referencing in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am using the online Share-Latex and trying the cite my sources and add the references at the end. However, nothing is working actually, I have tried to use all the packages available online!

I created a "library.bib" on Mendeley and I uploaded it up to Latex.
 I am using these commands:

```
\usepackage {natbib,har2nat}

\begin{document}

The Uk air pollution has long been regarded as a substantial health issue \CITE{XYZ2018}.

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A statement such as "nothing is working" is not particularly helpful. *What* precisely is "not working"? Do you get error messages? Did you try `\cite` instead `\CITE`? Did run a fully compilation sequence (LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX)? Have you checked the .log and .blg files for error and/or warning messages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the issue. A good MWE is sstarting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. We also need an example of a bib file to see if you have errors in it.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Actually, I tried \cite, \CITE, \citep, \citet... But what I always get is something like this: The Uk air pollution has long been regarded as a substantial health issue XYZ2018. And at the end of the document I get 
 the word "Reference" without any references.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you actually do. E.g., are you trying to run `biber` rather than `bibtex`? Please be precise.